# VTK custom IDs for vertices/edges in C++

Tags: c++, vtk

Forgive me as I'm rather new at VTK *and* C++ but I'm starting to get a handle on it but I guess I'm just not sure where to go from here.

I'm working on making a graph and when you select the vertices and edges, it displays which ones are selected (I used [this](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Graphs/SelectedVerticesAndEdges) tutorial as a starting point). It's done very well except instead of using the labels I've given each vertex, it merely uses the order in which it was created (or say the default value). I did a little research and saw that you could use a pedigree ID array for vertices (I don't know about edges but I'm taking one step at a time) and this will act as custom IDs, but I can't figure out how to implement this.

So I guess my main question here is this:

- Can I make custom IDs for each vertex that I can refer to later?

- Can I do this with edges as well?

- How do I go about this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Looking in the vtk documentation, `vtkGraph` class has 2 method `GetVertexData ()` and `GetEdgeData ()` which return an instance of `vtkDataSetAttributes`. This class allows to set an `vtkAbstractArray` (vtkIdType array, string array ... and more) as PedigreeIds. You may fill this array got from your graph, and set your pedigree id at the same position of the desired vertex to "labelize" the vertex (or edge).
2. Other solution is to create an associative array like `std::map<vtkIdType, vtkIdType>` with your Id as key, and the vertex Id associated as value. It will allow you to get the "real" ID in the graph from your choosen ID.
3. You can change the Id of one vertex, but you have to check others edges using it, to change the reference and set the new ID you choose, it can be expensive to seek and modify each vertex/edges linked with the modified ID.
4. You can set some label for the representation with the `vtkGraphLayoutView` class associated to vertex, but it's not internal to the Graph instance, but for the rendering. It should not be used for "relabelling" IDs.

I havn't tested any of these solutions. I hope it will help.